# Comparing Two Strings Java Style

Tags: java, compareto

I saw this in my readings that allows you to compare two strings using the compareToCaseIgnore(String).

```
public class CompareWithoutCase
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {
        String name1, name2;  // To hold two names

        // Create a Scanner object to read input.
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        // Get a name.
        System.out.print("Enter a name: ");
        name1 = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Get another name.
        System.out.print("Enter another name: ");
        name2 = keyboard.nextLine();

        // Compare the names.
        if (name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2) < 0)
        {
           System.out.println(name1 + " is less than " + name2);
        }
        else if (name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2) == 0)
        {
           System.out.println(name1 + " is equal to " + name2);
        }
        else if (name1.compareToIgnoreCase(name2) > 0)
        {
           System.out.println(name1 + " is greater than " + name2);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is why would a string such as cli be different from ilc in value if they hold the same characters? I've read in another question that a lower case letter is different from a capital letter in value and I somewhat understand that, though not fully. Is there any place I can find an explanation for this in depth or can someone explain with a few examples? I input

> cli

for the first string and

> ilc

for the second name and got

> cli is less than ilc

Why is one less than the other with the same letters in each string?

Comment: Please clarify your question and add a concrete example. Do you want to know why you cannot use `name1 == name2`?

Comment: well, for various comparison options, check: http://javarevisited.blogspot.de/2012/03/how-to-compare-two-string-in-java.html

Comment: It means that `"HELLO"` and `"hello"` are not equal. If you want to compare them as if they're equal, use `compareToIgnoreCase` (or `equalsIgnoreCase`). If you want to treat those strings as non-equal, then use `compareTo` or `equals`.

Comment: Strings defined equal if their content is identical.  Using your terminology, they have the same characters in the same order.

Comment: suppose you have an audio track named `foo.mp3` on your hard drive and you don't know where it is exactly located, so you go and search your hard drive for it by typing the string `foo.mp3` in some input field, what do you expect the result to be? maybe `3o.pfom` ???

Comment: As for why "cli" would be different from "ilc," it's for the same reason that "dog" isn't the same word as "god." Just saw your edit: "less than" is roughly equivalent to "would appear earlier in a dictionary."

Comment: I cant accept an answer for 5 minutes but nhgrif nailed my question on the head. Thank you guys for your answers.

Comment: and ya yshavit thank you that actually helps me visualize it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lower case and upper case letters do have different ASCII values, but they are separated by a constant (42, I think).  That is to say, `A` is the same distance from `a` as `B` is from `b` as `C` is from `c`, etc.

`ilc` and `cli` are different in that they're completely different characters.

`compareToIgnoreCase` (or `equalsIgnoreCase`) does a character by character comparison.  That is, it compares the character at index `0` of `str1` to the character at index `0` of `str2`.  And so on, for every index of the two strings being compared.

If you compare `ilc` and `cli`, then `i` in `ilc` is compared to `c` in `cli` (and they're different), so the comparison returns `false`.  The comparison doesn't care if `i` appears elsewhere in the second string, it only cares if `i` or `I` exists in the second string at the same index it exists in the first string (and so on for all the rest of the characters, though I imagine it's probably optimized to `return false` as soon as it finds one difference).

Comment: Thank you this makes perfect sense now.